# Jenkins server integration with bitbucket cloud

Tags: jenkins

Im new to jenkins server. I have a task. i will explain clearly here. I already created jenkins server on ubuntu ec2 server. my task that, 
1. jenkins should auto pull the code from bitbucket cloud(one repos url), when user raise Pull request. Then this code should send to unit testing.
2. If unit test passed , then this code send to future test like web testing as well jenkins send the unit test report as html report to user by mail notification. (if unit test failed then jobs should drop)
3. webtesting should run on maven project.(becuase the webtesting code have pom.xml file- which is used to test the code after the unit testing. This webtesting code in another repos url).
4. If webtesting passed ,then this report as html document send to user by mail notification. 
5. Then when  user merge and approve the code then jenkins should deploy the code on target server automatically. Then jenkins update build status(passwed/failed) in bitbucket cloud. Thats all

so finally im having two repos url, one for code deploy and another one for webtesting. Im new to jenkins server. I m struggling with jenkins server.Please help me to finish it.so please tell me the steps and what are the plug ins should i install and how to execute this? guide me ..i hope you people understand my task. 
else mail me: slakshminarayanan@live.com